# Is it possible to travel by air in India domestically with only a scanned pan card?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, air-india

I am from North India. I am thinking of going to Bengaluru via flight but I only have scanned copy of my pan card in my phone. Is it possible for me to travel without Aadar?